# Unable to modify shared applications WSO2 APIM 2.6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I installed WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 using a [distributed deployment (pattern 2)](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Deployment+Patterns) and I enabled [Application Sharing](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Sharing+Applications) in order to allow a group of users (with the same organization value) to be able to manage the organization applications.

For testing purpose, I created a user "user1" with organization "myorg". Then logged in with user1 and created an application "app1" with the group "myorg". After that, I logged in with another user belonging to the same organization and I am able to see the "app1" application. I'm also able to manage the application subscriptions, however I cannot edit and delete the application event if I assign the admin role.

Is there any way to able users from the same organization to modify shared applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application owners are able to [share their Applications](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Sharing+Applications) with others users who belong to the same group. Still, application edit privilege is granted to the app owner only, others can only view the application. This behavior is expected.

If you need to grant application edit privilege to another user, admin has to [change the ownership of the application](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Changing+the+Owner+of+an+Application). Then the new owner can edit the application.

Note: The owner changing UI is available in 2.6.0 as a WUM update only and will be there in the next public release. However, this is available in the admin API in the latest released versions.